# using the android new activity launcher tutorial

Tags: android, android-activity, android-launcher

I have followed the tutorial to the letter on the android developers website on how to launch a new activity. However there are 2 errors that I cant clear, and they are in code taken directly from the tutorial?

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);
        return rootView;
    }

    /** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class); //error 1
                EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message); //error 2
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

 }
```

error 1 is suggesting remove arguments to match intent()
error 2 is saying - Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method findViewById(int) from the type Activity

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

   <Button
   android:id="@id/button1"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/button_send" />

     </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you paste the stacktrace for your errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move this out of `Fragment`. The below must be in Activity.

```
 public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class); //error 1
            EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message); //error 2
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I guess you have

```
android:onClick="sendMessage"
```

for button in xml

I also guess the view belongs to the fragment layout. If the button  and EditText belongs to the `fragment_main.xml` then

```
  EditText editText;
 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
            false);
    editText = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.edit_message) 
    Button b = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1); //button id
    b.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener()
    {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View V) 
       {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DisplayMessageActivity.class); /
            String message = editText.getText().toString();
            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
            startActivity(intent);
       } 
    });  
    return rootView;
}
```

And you can get rid of  `android:onClick="sendMessage"`

Comment: when you say move this out of fragment it must be in activity. it was in my main activity.java? also could you explain why i don't require the onclick=sendmessage? thank you

Comment: @user3554481 no its is inside PlaceHolderFragment. secodnly if you have a listener for button you don't require `android:onClick="sendMessage"`. use the second part of my code

Comment: ive used it and tried changing the Id of the button in the xml to button1 but now im getting an error in the xml saying there is no resource found that matches that given name?

Comment: @JohnUKLD post your xmls

Comment: @JohnUKLD change to `android:id="@+id/button1"` `+` missing